# Unable to get websockets tests to pass in Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

Given a Django Channels consumer that looks like the following:

```
class NotificationConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("hello", "hello")
        self.accept()
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "hello", {"type": "chat.message", "content": "hello"}
        )

    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        print(content)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "hello", {"type": "chat.message", "content": "hello"}
        )
        print("Here we are")

    def chat_message(self, event):
        self.send_json(content=event["content"])

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("hello", "hello")
```

and a test that looks like the following:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestWebsockets:

    async def test_receives_data(self, settings):

        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
            application=application, path="/ws/notifications/"
        )
        connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
        assert connected
        await communicator.send_json_to({"type": "notify", "data": "who knows"})
        response = await communicator.receive_json_from()
        await communicator.disconnect()
```

I am always getting a `TimeoutError` when I run the test. What do I need to do differently?

If you'd like to see a full repo example, check out https://github.com/phildini/websockets-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't `async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("hello", "hello")` be `async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("hello", self.channel_name)`?
In the first case you are adding "hello" to the group and the `communicator.receive_json_from()` in the test will fail as the group_send will not be received by the test client.

By refactoring the class as:

```py
class NotificationConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("hello", self.channel_name)
        self.accept()
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "hello", {"type": "chat.message", "content": "hello"}
        )

    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        print(content)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "hello", {"type": "chat.message", "content": "hello"}
        )
        print("Here we are")

    def chat_message(self, event):
        self.send_json(content=event["content"])

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("hello", self.channel_name)
```

I can get the tests from the sample repo pass

Answer (score 1):

For testing async channels code you are best of using purely functional async tests.

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_receives_data(settings):
    communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
        application=application, path="/ws/notifications/"
    )
    connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
    assert connected
    await communicator.send_json_to({"type": "notify", "data": "who knows"})
    response = await communicator.receive_json_from()
    await communicator.disconnect()
```

pytest will let you mix theses with `class` based regular Django tests.

Here you can find some examples for testing consumers.

https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework/tree/master/tests

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for getting back. Adding a purely functional test still fails. Here's the gist of the output: https://gist.github.com/phildini/0424f6a6f30682d19002e60847f6989a